# Can a secret Facebook group be automatically synced with a Drupal site?

Tags: users, social-network, authentication-authorization

I have a Facebook secret group, and a Drupal membership site.

Members on the Drupal site (distinguished by a specific role) are added (and removed) manually from the “secret” Facebook group.

What works 
- Our Drupal site users log on to Facebook more than they log on to our Drupal site, so the secret group is a very convenient way to stay in touch with them.

What doesn’t work 
- We have to manually add and remove people from our Facebook site - things get out of sync.

Is there anything out there that would allow us to sync up the secret Facebook group with members of our site?

Comment: Voting to close, the crux of the question is about the FB API interaction with secret groups. That's a question more for StackOverflow, than for Drupal Answers.

Comment: @ShawnConn or to Facebook support. But I generally agree.